# Moving local wordpress to live server, thought I did everything right

Tags: wordpress, bluehost

[imgur link for reference](https://imgur.com/a/8i3k0ZO)

I am trying to get a custom wordpress site from my local server to my live one at Bluehost.

Here's everything I've done:

1. I've created new database on my live server
2. I've exported mysql database from my local server
3. In `wp-config.php` I've changed name of database, username and password accordingly with the database I've created on my live server
4. I've made a zip file of root directory ([dir] wp-admin, wp-config.php, index.php, etc)
5. On my live server I dropped everything and uploaded aforementioned exported database
6. On the file manager I uploaded the zip file into public_html and extracted everything

If I try to log into wordpress from the My Sites section of the Bluehost portal it brings me to a page that simply says "0". Even though I extracted the wordpress files into the `public_html` directory, is there still something else I'm supposed to do in terms of installation?

For what it's worth, when I initially set wordpress up it installed wordpress on its own, but I wanted to use my local one so I deleted the wordpress from the live server. It was my understanding that putting the root directory of my local wordpress site into the `public_html` folder would be the same thing as the 5 minute install, but it seems that I've messed up.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

### There's two recommended ways for doing that

1. Move manually. read this answer: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/193956/143910

---

2. Using plugins.   There's two good plugins for move your website from local to server

   a.[Duplicator](https://wordpress.org/plugins/duplicator/)

   b.[WP Clone](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-clone-by-wp-academy/)

Answer (score 0):

One necessary step which you did *not* mention:

You need to open the exported SQL file in an editor and find/replace every instance of the previous URL with the new URL (i.e. http://www.yourdomain.com/ replacing http://localhost/yourproject/. Then transfer it to the new server.

The reason: Wordpress saves all URLs / links etc. with *absolute* filepaths in the database. These filepaths need to be changed in order for the site to work on another server.